# apache nutch skip 'parse' stage

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I'm using apache nutch 1.10 version, and I'm changed sources to save raw htmls,css,js files to directory on local disk , all works fine but after fetching step comes a slow parse stage, how I can skip parsing?
I run crawling using  that command:

```
$ bin/crawl  urls/  data/ 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the bin/crawl script which will go over and over (*number of rounds* times) on the generate-fetch-parse-... steps. Check out the [nutch  tutorial](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial), you can issue any command by yourself (and building your own script) using bin/nutch.

However, if I understand what you are doing correctly, meaning indexing the html/css/js to a local filesystem, instead of changing the sources, you can [create your own plugins](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/WritingPluginExample) (you'll need a parse-plugin and an index-plugin I think), and apply them on the standard nutch process.